# Is it possible for me to reload only a bootstrap modal, without having to execute location.reload()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reload a bootstrap modal on its hidden event, so it will execute all my js functions over again once I open it later. It works if I execute location.reload, but it's kind of annoying having to wait for my page to reload in order for me to open my modal again. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Ajax to get data for the model.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { //modal hidden event
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        success: function(result){
            $('#myModal').html(result); //set new data to modal
            $('#myModal').modal('show'); //show the modal
        }
    });
});
```

#### Modal event for Bootstrap 3 and 4

[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) and [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)